# Update JS references in HTML page for different environments

Tags: javascript, html, build-process, build-automation

I have two types of generated JS files:

1. xyz.js
2. xyz.min.js

I want to refer both at different times, for different environments.

Currently I need to update the references manually, as there is large number of JS files: is there is any technique to avoid manual updating. Is this possible?

Comment: You question is not quite understandable. What have you tried? What exactly do you mean by references? Where do you have specific problems?

Comment: its like i want to change external js file reference in html page from one file to another based on context , whether i want to use minified version or original one.its like replacing 
<script src="xyz.js" > to <script src="xyz.min.js">

Comment: @user3418790 :  I hope you have clear idea about normal js file and min file because either you should use xyz.js or xyz.min.js there is no meaning to use both file.

Comment: yes right , I have a html page , for development purpose i need normal js files to be included while for deliverables i need minified one, so I am looking for something that enables me replacing those references as per requirement.

Comment: Something like http://requirejs.org?

Comment: No, now I understand a little... you want an automated build process, for two different environments. How do you already minify your files?

Comment: i used gruntjs, and for different deployments i have either minified version or normal version, now i don't want to add both references in my html file, as it will produce file load error, so i was looking for something so that html makes reference to either normal or minified , whichever is available there.

Comment: I got you bro, hold on a second

Answer (score 1):

Using GruntJS, you have multiple choices to solve this problem:

**1.** Point to one single file in your html and switch what version/type get's compiled into the different folders depending on the environment (by probably having at least two Grunt-Tasks):

`grunt build:dev` and `grunt build:live`

---

**2.** Use the [grunt-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml) package. You could again depending on your environment require [different targets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml#the-processhtml-task). Something like this (untested):

```

```
<!-- build:dev -->
<script src="js/lib/path/lib.js"></script>
<script src="js/deep/development/path/script.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->

<!-- build:dist -->
<script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->
```

```

There is also [grunt-targethtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-targethtml) or [grunt-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-preprocess/) or [grunt-htmlrefs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-htmlrefs)

---

**3.** Or only let it change the src to `.min` when building for the distribution-environment:

```

```
<!-- build:dist:js js/app.min.js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- /build -->

<!-- changed to -->
<script src="js/app.min.js"></script>
```

```

---

**4.** Assuming you use `grunt-uglify` you could again only point to one single file and then let grunt-uglify also generate [source-maps](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#source-maps). With these you serve minified versions to all environments, but also have a sourceMapping-file next to it, and when you view your code in the console/debugger it looks like development-code: [Introduction to JavaScript Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)

---

**5.** Reading an [article by Addy Osmani about this](https://addyosmani.com/blog/environment-specific-builds-with-grunt-gulp-or-broccoli/), he also points out string/regex replacement (excerpt taken from his article):

```
    'string-replace': {
      prod: {
        src: './app/**/*.html',
        dest: './dist/',
        options: {
          replacements: [{
            pattern: 'source.js',
            replacement: 'build.js'
          }]
        }
      }
```

---

**6.** He also mentions, you could use Template variables in HTML, and let `grunt-template` or `grunt-include-replace` let the work do for you.

Comment: hey  subastian, thanks bro. thanks for your time and  such  extensive and multiple solutions.  I got something like grunt-processhtml , i.e grunt-htmlrefs. thats was really helpfull . :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped @user3418790 ! You should consider accepting my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Use third party solutions is not good idea. Use helper class to include js and css files. Also you can add vesioning for your files (user does not need clear cache if your js changed).

In _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Html.IncludeJs("~/js/grid.js")
```

Source of IncludeJs extension method:

```
public static class JavascriptExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString IncludeJs(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename)
    {
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("minimizeJs") == "true")
        {
            filename = Regex.Replace(filename, "\.js$", ".min.js");
        }
        string version = GetVersion(helper, filename);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script src='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(filename) + version + "'></script>");
    }

    private static string GetVersion(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename)
    {
        var context = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;

        if (context.Cache[filename] == null)
        {
            var physicalPath = context.Server.MapPath(filename);
            var version = "?v=" + new System.IO.FileInfo(physicalPath).LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
            context.Cache.Add(physicalPath, version, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            context.Cache[filename] = version;
            return version;
        }
        else
        {
            return context.Cache[filename] as string;
        }
    }
```

}